# Running Kdiff3 command in silent mode

Tags: kdiff3

Does anyone know how to perform 3-way auto-merge of local files with "kdiff3" command in silent mode, without showing kdiff3 GUI regardless of the outcome of the merge?

What I'd like to see as behaviour of kdiff3 is as following:
- Kdiff3 returns a "0" code if the auto-merge is successful
- Kdiff3 returns <> "0" code if it requires a manual resolution of conflict

The command of kdiff3 that I will run:

```
kdiff3 -m file1 file2 file3 -o Outputfile --auto
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue as well.

Just open the kdiff3 gui, go to Settings > Configure KDiff3...

Then open the Merge tab, and make sure 'Show info dialogs' is unchecked.

[Merge Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltaz8.png)

When you run it next, it shouldn't come up with any info dialogs if you get successful merges.

Comment: This eliminates dialogs for successful merges, but it does not answer the question, which specified "without showing kdiff3 GUI regardless of the outcome of the merge".