# How Do I Make KDiff3 Not Show A GUI If All Conflicts Are Resolved?

Tags: kdiff3

KDiff3 ships with a diff3_cmd.bat for use with the svn diff3-cmd. See below (comments stripped)

```
SET DIFF3="C:\Program Files\KDiff3\kdiff3.exe"
SHIFT
SHIFT
SET MINE=%7
SET OLDER=%8
SET YOURS=%9
%DIFF3% %OLDER% %MINE% %YOURS% -o merged.txt
type merged.txt
del merged.txt
```

According to [the docs](https://docs.kde.org/trunk4/en/extragear-utils/kdiff3/documentation.html#idp50896672) I should be able to pass `--auto` to hide the GUI.

```
--auto    No GUI if all conflicts are auto-solvable. (Needs -o file)
```

However, it still pops up a dialog saying

```
Total number of conflicts: 6
Nr of automatically solved conflicts: 6
Nr of unsolved conflicts: 0
```

I tried adding `--cs "ShowInfoDialogs=0"`, however that hides the dialog when there are unresolved conflicts too.

Is there an option to hide the GUI completely on resolved conflicts but show the GUI and normal dialogs when there are conflicts?

Alternatively, is it possible to do a dry run to determine whether there are any unresolved conflicts then use `--cs "ShowInfoDialogs=0"` if it can be fully resolved and `--cs "ShowInfoDialogs=1"` if it will need manual intervention?

Comment: any luck with this?

Comment: I never got a resolution to this and now I'm no longer working on the same project that was using these scripts unfortunately.

Comment: Answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36288150/running-kdiff3-command-in-silent-mode